# UIWebView crashed while loading special url request

Tags: ios, uiwebview, crash, uiwebviewdelegate

In my case, I need to add some custom headers for some special requests.
so I add following code in UIWebViewDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSString *host = [[request URL] host];
static NSString *testTag = @"test_tag";

if ([host hasSuffix:@"yixin.im"]) // add special tag for special url(base on host)
{
    if ([[request allHTTPHeaderFields] objectForKey:testTag] == nil)
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest *aRequest = [request mutableCopy];
        [aRequest addValue:@"1" forHTTPHeaderField:testTag];
        [webView loadRequest:aRequest];            
        return NO;
    }
}
else //remove special tag for other url
{
    if ([[request allHTTPHeaderFields] objectForKey:testTag])
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest *aRequest = [request mutableCopy];
        [aRequest addValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:testTag];
        [webView loadRequest:aRequest];
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;

}
```

However, it crashed while loading the same url second times.
The crash stack is quite strange:

[image: crash stack]

I found that the crash is related to UIWebView cache. After removing ApplicationCache.db in Cache directory, it won't crash. However, I couldn't find the way to fix this crash.

My demo project is showed following: [crash project](http://nos.netease.com/yixinpublic/pr_fpone3azdbpyyp-9ebnf6a==_1418697881_60143). Follow the next two step, you will see the crash.

1. launch the app,you will see a webpage.
2. then relaunch the app,it crashes.

Some methods I have tried:

1.replace addValue:forHTTPHeaderField: by setValue:forHTTPHeaderField, it didn't work.

2.reset http headers by calling setAllHTTPHeaderFields:,it didn't work too.

3.replace nil by @"",it didn't work to.

4.replace return NO by return YES,it works...However,it doesn't make sense....

Comment: I download project and perform steps you said, but did not crash, page is open every time but have message "404 Not Found"

Comment: I update the project and replace the link.Can you download it and try it again?

Comment: now it's crashing after runnig app around 4~5

Comment: please update me that my research helped you or not ?

Comment: Do you remove your answer? I tried your method and it didn't help.I even reset headers by calling setAllHTTPHeaderFields: . however, it still crashes.

Comment: yes i did remove as it is not useful.

Comment: Did it crash when you set:@"" instead of nil (first remove your application and check again)

Comment: It still crash.I have almost tried all the different methods to reset the headers.however none of them did work.